# What event led to Eddie Brock leaving New York City

Tags: plot-explanation, character, venom

In the movie *Venom*, Eddie Brock and his fiancée Anne discuss an event that caused him to leave New York during a date.

They lightly allude to the situation from different perspectives, one saying he ran off, the other saying he just moved to be with her in San Francisco.

I vaguely recall a reference to a "Daily Globe" which sounds like a newspaper but not the one that Peter Parker/Spiderman works for.

Did the script/dialogue include any other details about what caused that departure?

> I know in the comics Eddie was a photographer competitor to Peter Parker so the comics may not match this origin story

Comment: As I recall, there's no exposition of it in the film other than the lines you mention, but in the comics Eddie Brock was run out of the Daily Bugle after Peter Parker proved he was faking his photos.  Since Eddie isn't a photographer in the movie, this probably wasn't the reason for his NYC exit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will leave this for now in case there are other answers from other folks more familiar with the source.

According to a [ScreenRant article](https://screenrant.com/venom-movie-easter-eggs-references-mcu/15/?v=8)

> There are several allusions to Eddie's past work as a reporter in New York, which is also where his comic book story begins - and where it ends in embarrassment, after his investigation into a criminal called The Sin-Eater is foiled by Spider-Man catching the real guy. The movie doesn't go into details, but it does call out the Daily Globe by name - the rival newspaper to the famous Daily Bugle - as Eddie previous place of employment. However, things didn't go too bad when Eddie left, judging by his text messages.
>
> During a short montage of Eddie looking for work, he's shown texting someone for a possible lead on a job. That someone is listed as Barney Bushkin, editor of the Daily Globe, and fierce enemy of J. Jonah Jameson.

TIL that there was a rival newspaper to the *Daily Bugle* and that its editor was a nemesis to J. Jonah Jameson!

However, since Spiderman likely won't share the screen with Venom in the foreseeable future, this comics background is not movie canon

Comment: After a few weeks of the movie being out, no other responses came about.  I figured interviews with actor, director, screenwriter may have addressed it but it was ultimately a small detail